# Show Ansible Steps as Separate Tasks in a GitHub Action

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile, github-actions, cicd

To test an ansible playbook, I have a Dockerfile that's called in a GitHub action as shown:

```
FROM ubuntu-22.04
RUN apt install -y dependencies
...
RUN ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

I also have a GitHub Action that builds the Docker image:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: docker build .
```

However, running the code this way means that all of the Docker setup instructions and Ansible steps show as one task in the GitHub Action. Is it possible to either

1. Split up the Docker steps (layers) into different tasks within the job on GitHub Actions, or
2. Within the Ansible playbook, make each individual step its own task on GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 2):

You can split your Dockerfile into multiple parts. To do that you can name your stages, by adding an `AS <stage-name>` to the `FROM` instruction.

```
FROM ubuntu-22.04 AS base

FROM base AS dependencies
RUN apt install -y dependencies

FROM dependencies AS ansible
RUN ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Then during the build, you can specify a target build stage, such as:

```
docker build --target base -t <repo>/<project-name>:<version> .
```

This is the link to the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).